# How to map urls?

Tags: aem, sling

I would like to map pages such `domain/content/myProject/home.html` to `domain/home.html`.  `/content/myProject/` is not needed. I have the following code:

```
 String newpath = getResourceResolver().map(page.getPath());
```

this does not change anything. newpath is stay `page.getPath()`

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have the mapping set at "/etc/map/http" ?

Comment: As Sarath mentioned either have the mapping in /etc/map/http or in OSGi in the URL Mappings from the Resource Resolver Factory. If it is only relevant for home you could also use a vanity path in the page properties.

Answer (score 1):

Answering as this question as it remains unanswered. Here is an example of how the etc mappings should look like:
[image]

Trick is you add 2 entries to sling:internalRedirect as / and /content/example/

AEM first tries to resolve resources with first entry '/'. So non page URLs like /etc/designs, /content/dam etc will be addressed by the first entry. If it is unable to resolve using the first one, it uses the second entry to resolve the page.

This is also the adobe recommended way for URL shortening compared to other techniques like apache redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create map in etc.Then Resource Resolver will take care of trimming the path .

**CREATING MAPPING DEFINITIONS IN AEM**

In a standard installation of AEM you can find the folder:

/etc/map/http

This is the structure used when defining mappings for the HTTP protocol. Other folders (sling:Folder) can be created under /etc/map for any other protocols that you want to map.
Configuring an Internal Redirect to /content

To create the mapping that prefixes any request to 
http://localhost:4503/ with /content:

1. Using CRXDE navigate to /etc/map/http.
2. Create a new node:
3. Type sling:Mapping
4. This node type is intended for such mappings, though its use is not mandatory.
5. Name localhost_any
6. Click Save All.
7. Add the following properties to this node:
        
   Name sling:match 

   Type String 

   Value localhost.4503/

   Name sling:internalRedirect 

   Type String 

   Value /content/

   Click Save All.

   This will handle a request such as:
        localhost:4503/geometrixx/en/products.html
   as if:
       localhost:4503/content/geometrixx/en/products.html
   had been requested.

   You can refer here for further documentation http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/resource_mapping.html

Comment: That will redirect everything including /etc/designs and /content/dam which will all fail to resolve.